# app..get() does not seem to work in the Node.js Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Here is the app.js file:

```
 var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    api = require('./routes/api.js'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');
    var app=  module.exports = express();



/**
 * Configuration
 */

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);

// development only
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

// production only
if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  // TODO
};

/**
 * Routes
 */

// serve index and view partials
app.get('/', routes.index);

// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', routes.index);


api(app);


/**
 * Start Server
 */

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Here is the routes/api.js file:

```
var queryObj = {

    retrieve:{

        api_path:'/api/test/list',
        var_name:''
    }

};

// All supporting functions used below are defined here !

module.exports = function(app) {

 _.each(queryObj, function(obj) {

        console.log("Check point 1");
        var args = [obj.api_path, function(req, res){

            var search_term = obj.var_name ? req.params[obj.var_name] : '';
            get(search_term,res);
            }];

         console.log("Check point 2");
        console.log("args:" + args);
        app.get.apply(app,args);
    });
   };
```

Here is the routes/index.js file:

```
/*
 * GET home page.
 */

exports.index = function(req, res){
 console.log("Default view");
  res.render('index');
};
```

So when i run this application and type **localhost:3001/api/test/list** in the browser, i get follwing output on the console:

Check point 1
Check point 2
`args: args:/api/alarms/list,function (req, res){

var search_term = obj.var_name ? req.params[obj.var_name] : '';
get(search_term,res);
}`

Express server listening on port 3001
Default view

My question is: why is `app.get.apply()` not working?  Instead the default route configured in app.js is taken up!

Comment: The output on the console is visible after you open the page in the browser or before? In your output it says `/api/alarms/list`, is that a copy&paste error? Because in your source code it says `api/test/list`.

Comment: Thats a copy paste error! This part of output:                    "Check point 1
Check point 2
`args: args:/api/test/list,function (req, res){

var search_term = obj.var_name ? req.params[obj.var_name] : '';
get(search_term,res); }`

Express server listening on port 3001 ". appears after launching the application. "Default view"  appears on console after i type the url in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the order of your route definitions: from most specific (in this case `api/test/list` to less specific `*`:

```
// defined api
api(app);

// serve index and view partials
app.get('/', routes.index);

// redirect all others to the index (HTML5 history)
app.get('*', routes.index);
```

Comment: Tried it! Still the same results !:(

Comment: I've copy&pasted your code and changed the order and I get the following error message when browsing to `api/test/list`: `ReferenceError: get is not defined`. Have you changed anything else? Try removing your `*` route and see what happens.

Comment: Ohh, it seems to be working for you then ! You are getting "api/test/list: ReferenceError: get is not defined "because  get(search_term,res) is not defined in the file api.js. if i remove * route then i get following error: "Cannot GET /api/test/list". I have not changed anything else in my code.

Comment: Add the following line to your `app.js` after the route definitions: `console.log(app.routes);`. This will output all defined routes on your console.

Comment: Hey console.log(app.routes) helped a lot ! There was a typo in api_path variable in my code. I corrected it. So once i changed the order as you suggested, app.get.apply() seems to work. Thanks !